# ipe latex text not able to run

Tags: pdftex, technical-drawing, ipe

I was trying to add latex text/symbols in ipe tools, but it's popping out error shown in the image.
I tried to add the path as an environment variable as C:\Users\Pramod\AppData\Local\ipe where "runlatex" file located , still got the same error. Please could you please help?[image]

Comment: Did you install LaTeX, e. g. MiKTeX?

Comment: Maybe read the last sentence of the error message more closely. This sounds like a convenient solution.

Comment: @Manuel ,yes I have installed MikTeX  2.9,

Comment: The last-mentioned solution is not working even after enabling online compile.

Comment: a few days back I have modified the registry for some software and forgot to take backup, Is this error anything to do with the registry ?

Comment: Just add the LaTeX bin directory to your path. How you do that depends on your Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, replying here, the issue is resolved - The problem was is in the registry, solved using [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEyNiqsvXpAhXhzDgGHe52AOUQwqsBMAp6BAgJEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSnZu6HNmIiY&usg=AOvVaw0Xh_vDwMt5mymJ4Yi2wGAd) .hence command prompt was also not opening.

Comment: Is it possible that you are the same person as the original poster, but have two accounts?  If so, you can get them merged: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232